# Configure SSH to allow port forwarding but no commands for particular key?

Tags: security, ssh

So I've added a public key to `authorized_keys`. How can I limit it so that it may forward ports but it may not have a shell?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to add `no-pty,command="/bin/false"` keyword before your key so it will look like this:

```
no-pty,command="/bin/false" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABBACzbcwCZNaN3HhHmpnaVrfZlNJ0HhPnOqEj
k2llms1OOPnEXetIlZuJw0UXbyMbhQbBl/E2wxXvXvF+jyLRR5yN6kBydM4LhjC0ej0PcH839vXd
uwJpDFjPw3s7r0VOhU1WRyk6Da6rX6shzabhQioIm3MHCjNOdywPb0k1cTj4yOxoOCOqGjmXK0
xxzTd+ZjTJqQGWzZ+8L8cVtKmU8kspYlCdhGWSv0Den36OsScnWTBn8A3X3lVJB5NkEm
BM1yKX4F6BhhD317VensEUu031PtFULeSF97IxDPmK36OFz9TPSf4d8Hp3BqtysqUlbWfEhYdHXj
+1Mn4xXZKiZhBh1DX youruser@yourhome
```

(This is all in a single line, I added the line breaks for readability).

Comment: That restricts the ability to have a remote login, it does not prevent remote execution of commands. Src: http://marc.info/?l=openssh-unix-dev&m=111143581515782&w=2

Comment: @mctylr: that was not part of the question. But you are right maybe the OP was not aware of that, so I added that to the answer. (+1)

Comment: Also worth noting is that you need to use 'ssh -N' to keep the tunnel up when there is no shell at the remote end.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at using [scponly](https://github.com/scponly/scponly), I suspect it can be used for port forwarding rather than scp/sftp-only access. It is intended to restrict the user from logging in or executing commands via ssh.

The other factor you may need to, or want to, use sshd in a [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot)'ed environment, here are some [instructions on setting up sftp using chroot.](http://www.netadmintools.com/art294.html) You should be able to adapt them fairly easily.

I hope that helps you find your solution.

Comment: `scponly` seems to have moved to https://github.com/scponly/scponly .  Your link gives a 404.  :(

Answer (score 1):

> man sshd

Section **AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT**. You can restrict what users can port forward to simply by adding the ports and hosts you want to allow, like

> permitopen="192.0.2.1:80"

Also you can restrict where do the user connect from, which commands can execute, etc.